# How can I store GPS parameters to a DB in an efficient way?

Tags: multithreading, sqlite, gps

I'm trying to make an app to store GPS parameters to a SQLite Database.

I've searched for posts in this line, and I finally manage to pass the parameters (in String type) to the main activity through the SharedPreferences and that was perfect, I can save the positions to the database, but just manually. I want to insert a line in the DB everytime location changes, so I start a new code trying to access to the DB directly from the OnLocationChanged method but the program crash at the start, I don't know where is the error. Here it is the code:

```
package com.example.trackinggps;
import com.example.trackinggps.GPSSQLiteHelper;
import android.os.Bundle;[..]//Hiden

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    public Button Close;
    public int num=0;
    public LocationManager locationManager=null;    

    GPSSQLiteHelper usdbh = new GPSSQLiteHelper(this, "GPSTracking", null, 1);
    final SQLiteDatabase db = usdbh.getWritableDatabase();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        if(db!=null){
          Close = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button4);

          final LocationUpdateHandler lUH = new LocationUpdateHandler();

          locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

          locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 1500,0, lUH);      

          Close.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){ [..]//Impl. Hiden
          Close.setOnLongClickListener(new OnLongClickListener(){ [..]//Impl. Hiden
        }
    }


    public class LocationUpdateHandler implements LocationListener {

        @Override
        public void onLocationChanged(Location loc) {
            String lat = (String) Double.toString(loc.getLatitude());
            String lng = (String) Double.toString(loc.getLongitude());
            String acc = (String) Float.toString(loc.getAccuracy());
            String spd= (String) Float.toString(loc.getSpeed());
            String time=(String) Long.toString(loc.getTime());

            if(db!=null){
                db.execSQL("INSERT INTO GPSTracking (Id, Time, Longitude, Latitude, Accuracy, Speed ) " +"VALUES ("+ num +", '" + 
                    time + "' , '" + lat + "' , '" + lng + "' , '" + acc + "' , '" + spd + "')");

                num++;
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {}
        @Override
        public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {}
        @Override
        public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, 
                Bundle extras) {}
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu){ [..]//Impl. Hiden
}
```

The Logcat result, was this one:

```
Shutting down VM
threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40014760)
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.example.trackinggps/com.example.trackinggps.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1660)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1752)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:123)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:993)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:126)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3997)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:491)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:841)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:599)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at android.content.ContextWrapper.openOrCreateDatabase(ContextWrapper.java:221)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:149)
    at com.example.trackinggps.MainActivity.<init>(MainActivity.java:28)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstanceImpl(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1424)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1022)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1651)
    ... 11 more
```

Comment: Why can't you access the DB from `OnLocationChanged`?

Comment: First I declared the SQLiteHelper and the SQLiteDatabase outside the onCreate method of the main activity, to have access to them from the LocationUpdateHandler but it crashed when starting to execute in the Virtual Device. So I guessed that was not posible :/

Comment: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.example.trackinggps/com.example.trackinggps.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException

Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
at android.content.ContextWrapper.openOrCreateDatabase
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase
at com.example.trackinggps.MainActivity.<init>

Comment: All that information belongs into the question, together with the initialization code of the `MainActivity`.

Comment: Sorry, I don't know exactly what you mean... Do I have to put it in the initialization code, before the onCreate method? But I don't know how to solve those problems

Comment: Edit your question to show all the information.

Comment: Edited. I've tried to omit the unimportant part of the code.

Comment: Show the source of the `GPSSQLiteHelper` constructor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it. I have instantiated the db inside the OnLocationchanged method so that the program works:

```
 [..]

 public class MainActivity extends Activity {

 [..]   


         GPSSQLiteHelper usdbh = new GPSSQLiteHelper(this, "GPSTracking", null, 1);        
         SQLiteDatabase db = null;

    @Override   
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

             [..]
         }

        public class LocationUpdateHandler implements LocationListener {

          @Override 
          public void onLocationChanged(Location loc) {

            db = usdbh.getWritableDatabase();

                [..]
          }
        [..]
        }

}
```